# what is the hook for woocommerce backend orders table?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i am trying to figure out the hook to use to add code to the backend woocommerce orders table. any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hooks to create custom columns and their associated data for a custom post type are [`manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_columns) and  [`manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column) respectively, where `{$post_type}` is the name of the custom post type.

Here is example

```
add_filter( 'manage_shop_order_posts_columns', 'set_custom_edit_post_columns',99,1 );
function set_custom_edit_post_columns($columns) {
    $columns['custom-columns'] = __( 'Columns Name', 'your_text_domain' );
    return $columns;
}
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_cpost_column', 99, 2 );
function custom_cpost_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {

        case 'custom-columns'://new-title=your column slug :
            echo 'custom columns value' ;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: if i wanted to get information of each row's order and order data, for example adding a button that prints the order invoice for shipping, how would i go about that?

Comment: in second function (`custom_cpost_column`) you have $post_id,  using this in switch  case `'custom-columns'`  get the data of order.

Comment: i have a very rough proof of concept completed. however using your code when i output the data each row shows data of the very first row's data only. if you have time i can send you video of this offline and the git repo link?

Comment: @HollerTrain share your code links and video links

Comment: this is the code i have so far - not the greatest syntax and pretty rough just to get a proof of concept going - https://pastebin.com/tFFz2mPP - the video would show sensitive data since it is live site. what do i need to edit in this code to make the data show per each row in the Orders view in woocommerce?

Comment: @HollerTrain are you try for  create order invoice ?

Comment: yes essentially. i have the data that i need showing in a lightbox so everything is fine. i just need this to work per each row in the orders table. right now it just shows the first record's data on every record

Comment: Why are you not used plugin for print invoice?. there are lot of free plugin available  for this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150824/discussion-between-ankur-bhadania-and-hollertrain).

Comment: hey i am online and able to chat now

Comment: @HollerTrain Please check chat